# Logging with not defined logger in config

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to use logging in my package with predefined configuration in YAML format. Something like this:

```yaml
## config.yaml

version: 1
formatters:
  complex:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  simple:
    format : '%(name)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s'
handlers:
  console:
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    level: WARNING
    formatter: simple
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
  file:
    class: logging.FileHandler
    level: DEBUG
    formatter: complex
    filename: "debug.log"
loggers:
  Example:
    level: DEBUG
    handlers: [console, file]

Root:
  Level: DEBUG
  handlers: [console]
```

When I create a new logger with predefined names in my configuration, in this case, `Example`, logging works as expected but when I create a logger with another name, for example, `__name__` name of the module, it uses *maybe* some default configurations, because outputs from `warning` level.

I assumed it will use `Root`'s configuration, but it does not.

First I want to understand how this part in logging works, when I pass an unknown logger name, and is there a way to predefine configurations for this case (logger with name `__name__` of file)?

Comment: Why do you think it's not using the root configuration? The only handler for that is the console, which only outputs warnings and above.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I changed the level of the console to DEBUG, but still, it outputs from WARNING and above level, also in Root's level it's defined DEBUG, would it override the console settings?